# Enable Django Form Internationalization

Tags: django, forms, internationalization

I'm struggling to enable internationalization in forms. As far as I understood the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms) and posts that I read, one has to add the following settings to the app to make form internationalization work.

1. Set USE_L10N to True in settings.py; USE_L10N = True
2. Set locale in view:

   ```
   import locale
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
   ```
3. For each form field set localize to True:

   ```
   class ExpenditureForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Expenditure
           fields = ('gross_value', 'tax', 'receipt_date', 'currency', 'description', 'receipt',)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(ExpenditureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['gross_value'].localize = True
       self.fields['gross_value'].widget.is_localized = True #added this as reaction to comments.
   ```

The simplified model looks like this:

```
class Expenditure(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    purchase_order_membership = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrderMembership)
    month = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=2)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=4)
    net_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    gross_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

I executed these steps, but Django still only accepts number inputs with a dot as the decimal separator, instead of the comma as the decimal separator as needed in German notation.

So probably I missed a step. I'm also not sure where to set the locale. I think the view is not the proper place to do. Would be not very DRY to set the locale in the view for each request.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to activate german `translation.activate('de_DE')` ? `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate  (You can import translation from django.utils )

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried it but unfortunately it does not change anything.

Comment: Also: `self.fields['gross_value'].widget.is_localized = True` ! it works for me.

Comment: Hmm.. Indeed it has to do something with the LANGUAGE_CODE. If I set the LANGUAGE_CODE setting to 'de_DE' in settings.py it works. If I set the LANGUAGE_CODE setting to 'en-us' it is ignored that I re-set the language code in the view translation.activate('de_DE') and form field validation is done in en-us style. Do you set the language code in settings.py or in the view?

Comment: The reason that I want to localize the form field validation / presentation  at runtime is that I have users from different regions. Therefore I have to be able to set the form field validation at runtime.

Comment: Runs in a customer web: www.rentit.es (test it but don't complete booking ;). For german, I change language in middleware with `translation.activate('de')`.  (you can appreciate locales in date format for german)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27032/discussion-between-tom-and-danihp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is right, also `settings.py` . Elegant way is to set translation activate in a middleware, but in view. See [stefanw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336889/842935) for details, I quote answer here:

```
from django.utils import translation

class LocaleMiddleware(object):
    """
    This is a very simple middleware that parses a request
    and decides what translation object to install in the current
    thread context. This allows pages to be dynamically
    translated to the language the user desires (if the language
    is available, of course).
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        language = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
        translation.activate(language)
        request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
```

Remember to register the middleware.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. language has to be activated in a middleware. Activating it in the view does not work, and does not make much sense.