# WSGI Process won't reload after changing the wsgi script file

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm running a Django site on Apache2.2 with mod_wsgi 3.3 in daemon mode (on Debian Wheezy).

When I use the `touch wsgi.py` command on my WSGI script from my shell, the process is reloaded and everything works fine. But, when I modify the `wsgi.py` file from the web-application code, the modification time is correctly changed (checked by `stat`) but WSGI process **is not restarted**. I'm using the same user account when manually touching the file as WSGI-daemon runs under.

I've tried the following two methods for "touching" the file from the web-app code, none of which works:

1. os.system('touch /abs/path/to/wsgi.py')
2. using django-rosetta's ROSETTA_WSGI_AUTO_RELOAD setting to do the job for me

Both options above actually do seem to work exactly as when I execute `touch` manually from the shell. They update all *Access, Modify and Change* file attributes (I'm using ext4, if that could matter).

I know it's really strange behavior and after I've read all docs I'm hopeless. Does anyone have at least a clue what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do be aware that the reload only occurs on the next request received by the web application. It is not instantaneous at the point that you touch the wsgi.py file. Although you seem to suggest this isn't the issue, Apache would also normally run as a special user and would not have the ability to modify the WSGI script file unless you had specifically set up permissions to allow it to.

To better determine what is going on, ensure that LogLevel is set to info in Apache configuration and look at what log messages mod_wsgi generates in the Apache error log.

For more details and other ways of triggering reload see:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: Thanks, it's obvious now that the WSGI process was reloading, but the problem was in locale initialization. Still interesting problem, because i found out that if i change the default locale (with translation.activate() call) in the first request-response cycle after WSGI process is started, it will remain changed forever - untill next process reload. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, finally found the solution. I was using a custom middleware changing the locale for some URLs. The middleware, however, wasn't calling `translation.deactivate()` at the end of the request (`process_response` method) which obviously led to some weird inter-thread sharing of locale selection, thus affecting also all further requests. This was happening only when the middleware changed the locale on the first request after process start.

More info here: [set language within a django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336785/set-language-within-a-django-view#comment12481631_2336889)