# How to add new locale at runtime in Django?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have situation when i have two types of locales. First needed for website and second need for creating reports. Second type of locales added dynamically so it cant be set in settings.

Im interesting is there possibility to add new locales at runtime?

Comment: are you talking about change locale at runtime to make report and comeback to user locale?

Comment: yes, but report locale and website locale are different files, so i need somehow to load report locales to django at runtime

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336889/4151886) and [django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#localized-names-of-languages),

You can do this in your view:

```
from django.utils import translation
```

and

```
language = second_type_locales
translation.activate(language)
```

here comes some [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) in django document,