# Set language of PasswordResetForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I am manually resetting passwords but wonder how to set the language to the user's language instead of my own. I see there are many extra context fields but which one needs to be set?

```
for user in qs:
    reset_form = PasswordResetForm({'email': user.email})
    # reset_form.language?
    assert reset_form.is_valid()
    reset_form.save(request=request)
```

I have added a field `CustomUser.language` which would be available in `user.language` above.

*(While phrasing my question and looking for possibilities I found a working solution.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the following solution, by setting the current language (session-wise) temporarily to the user's language:

```
from django.utils import translation

temp_language = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
for user in qs:
    translation.activate(user.language)
    request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
    reset_form = PasswordResetForm({'email': user.email})
    assert reset_form.is_valid()
    reset_form.save(request=request)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336785/set-language-within-a-django-view/2336889#comment12481631_2336889
    translation.deactivate()
translation.activate(temp_language)
request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
```

Comment: Instead of `activate` and `deactivate` you can also use `with translation.override(user.language)`.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić if you post a working answer with it I'll accept it